# Using paging (Skip, Take) over multiple DbSets

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have an Entity Framework DbContext with two different DbSets.

In my view I am combining these two sets into the same view model and listing them in the same table.

I want to support table paging to be able to query only a page of records at a time sorted by a particular column.  I can't see how to do this without reading all of the records from the database and then paging from memory.

For example, I want to be able to sort by date ascending since both tables have a date column.  I could simply take the page size from both tables and then sort in memory but the problem comes into play when I am skipping records.  I do not know how many to skip in each table since it depends on how many records are found in the other table.

Is there a way to manipulate Entity Framework to do this?

Comment: Combine them in the database instead

Comment: What do you mean by "Combining"? Is this a union?

Comment: Create a database view that performs the joins and projections to "combine" the sets, expose your view to the application by DBML mapping in EF, then use Skip/Take on the mapped type.

Comment: Whatever it is, performance iwll be bad. First x (or x in a page) of 2 disparate indices means putting all into a temp table then selecting of that. The performance will be horrific.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

- JOin them in the database (can be done in EF).
- Project that (select new  {}) into the final object
- Order by, skip, take on that projection.

It will be crap performance wise but there is no way around that given you have a broken database model. It basically has to get a tempoary view of all rows for the SQL to find the first ones - that will be slow.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is going to be to combine them with a stored procedure or view, and then map that sp/view into Entity Framework. Combing them on the client is going to kill performance - let the server do it for you; it is clearly a server side task.

Comment: Cant do `Skip` `Take` on the result of a SP (and have it run in the DB) View would be better.

Comment: Except if you do the skip/take yourself in the SP via parameters passed into the SP, but your point is well taken, it might be easier to use a view unless there are other reasons for relying on an SP, in which case the skip take logic would need to be included in the SP.